# Changing Oracle 11g SYSTEM Password

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to change my SYSTEM password in 11G Oracle.

---

When Entered Command in Cmd

```
C:\Users\ranvi>sqlplus "/as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Oct 8 20:59:06 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Enter user-name:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XZ8z.png)

Comment: The "/ as sysdba" syntax instructs an OS authentication. In order for this to succeed, your user needs to be a member of Windows group "ORA_DBA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus system

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Uto Lis 8 20:38:05 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

---

`System` doesn't have to connect as `sysdba` (but `sys` does):

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus sys

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Uto Lis 8 20:38:49 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER


Enter user-name:
```

So:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Uto Lis 8 20:39:17 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```